# Subroutine is returning NaN. Class variable issue?

Tags: fortran90

I am having issues with a simple code I have written. subroutine energy is supposed to calculate the energy of the system, and is frequently returning NaN. The reason why it is doing that is because a value dd, distance between particles, is becoming zero and I have no idea why. I am relatively new to Fortran, and I believe maybe it has something to do with how I am passing class variables around which is why I came here. The code and modules are as follows.

module get started defines a class andreads values from an input file and prints to screen.

```
module get_started

  implicit none

  type input

     integer :: np
     integer :: istart
     integer :: mceq,mcsteps
     integer :: nsample, nadjust
     double precision :: rcut,rcut2,rv,rv2,rcrv2
     double precision :: maxd
     double precision :: vol,box,hbox
     double precision :: eps,sig
     double precision :: dens
     double precision :: temp


  end type input

contains

  subroutine init(param)

    implicit none
    type(input) :: param

    open(unit=1,file='input')

    read(1,*)param%rcut
    read(1,*)param%np               ! system's size
    read(1,*)param%dens             ! thermodynamical conditions
    read(1,*)param%temp
    read(1,*)param%istart
    read(1,*)param%maxd
    read(1,*)param%mceq,param%mcsteps
    read(1,*)param%nsample
    read(1,*)param%nadjust

    param%eps   = 1.0d0
    param%sig   = 1.0d0

    param%rcut2 = param%rcut*param%rcut
    param%rv    = 1.1*param%rcut
    param%rv2   = param%rv*param%rv
    param%rcrv2 = (param%rv-param%rcut) * (param%rv-param%rcut)

    param%vol   = param%np/param%dens
    param%box   = param%vol**(1.0d0/3.0d0)
    param%hbox  = param%hbox/2

    return
  end subroutine init


  subroutine print_input(param)

    implicit none
    type(input):: param

    print*
    print*,' A Monte Carlo program for Lennard-Jones particles'
    print*,' -------------------------------------------------'


    print*,' Lennard-Jones parameters:'
    print*,'   np=',param%np
    print*,'   eps= ',param%eps
    print*,'   sig= ',param%sig
    print*,'   rcut= ',param%rcut
    print*,'   rv  =',param%rv
    print*,'   rv2 =',param%rv2 
    print*

    print*,' Simulation box length: ',param%box
    print*,' Volume               : ',param%vol
    print*,' Number density       : ',param%dens
    print*,' Temperature          : ',param%temp
    print*

    print*
    print*,' maxd           : ',param%maxd
    print*,' # eq steps     : ',param%mceq
    print*,' # MC steps     : ',param%mcsteps
    print*,' Sampling freq  : ',param%nsample
    print*,' Adjusting freq : ',param%nadjust
    print*

    return
  end subroutine print_input

end module get_started
```

module position initializes the positions of the particles

```
module position

  use get_started

  implicit none
  integer:: numpd
  double precision ::gsize
  integer :: i,j,k
  integer :: flag


contains

  subroutine init_position(param,x,y,z,flag)

    implicit none
    type(input),intent(in)   :: param
    double precision :: x(param%np),y(param%np),z(param%np)
    integer :: counter,flag

    numpd = ceiling(param%np**(1.0d0/3.0d0))
    print*,'numpd',numpd
    print*,'box',param%box
    gsize = param%box/numpd
    print*,'gsize',gsize


    if(flag.eq.0) then
       counter =1

       do i=1,numpd
          do j=1,numpd
             do k=1,numpd

                if(counter.le.param%np)then
                   y(counter) = i*gsize
                   z(counter) = j*gsize
                   x(counter) = k*gsize
                endif
                counter = counter+1

             enddo
          enddo
       enddo

    else if(flag.eq.1) then

       do i=1,param%np
          x(i) = ran()*param%box
          y(i) = ran()*param%box
          z(i) = ran()*param%box
       enddo

    end if


    open(unit=2,file='posit.dat')
    do i =1,param%np
       write(2,*)x(i),y(i),z(i)
    enddo

    close(unit=2)

    return
  end subroutine init_position

end module position
```

module modmove_energy is where all the action is at. In this module, the subroutines which apply the monte carlo move (picking a particle, random displacement, and accepting or rejecting move) along with the energy calclulation (this is where the error is) are contained. It is the variable dd in energy which is returning zero for non identical particles frequently, and hence causing the NaN error.

```
module modmove_energy

use get_started

contains

  ! note random generator function
  subroutine move(potential,param,x,y,z,ar)
    implicit none
    integer :: ar,it,step
    type(input),intent(in) :: param
    double precision :: potential
    double precision :: x(param%np),y(param%np),z(param%np)
    double precision :: xold,yold,zold,drxold,dryold,drzold
    double precision :: dr2
    double precision :: uold,unew,delta
    double precision :: alpha,beta,gamma


    it = int(ran()*param%np)+1

    call energy(uold,x,y,z,param)



    alpha =param%maxd*(ran()-0.5)
    beta  =param%maxd*(ran()-0.5)
    gamma =param%maxd*(ran()-0.5)

    x(it) = x(it) + alpha

    y(it) = y(it) + beta

    z(it) = z(it) + gamma


    if (x(it) > param%box) then
       x(it)=x(it)-param%box
    elseif  (x(it) < 0.d0) then
       x(it)=x(it)+param%box
    endif

    if (y(it) > param%box) then
       y(it)=y(it)-param%box 
    else if (y(it) < 0.d0) then
       y(it)=y(it)+param%box
    endif

    if (z(it) > param%box) then
       z(it)=z(it)-param%box
    else if (z(it) < 0.d0) then
       z(it)=z(it)+param%box
    endif


   call energy(unew,x,y,z,param)

    delta = unew-uold


    if (delta < 0.) then
       potential=potential+delta
       ar=1
    elseif (exp(-delta/(param%temp)) >= ran()) then
       potential=potential+delta
       ar=1
    else
       x(it)=xold
       y(it)=yold
       z(it)=zold
       ar=0
  endif



  end subroutine move




  subroutine energy(u,x,y,z,param)

    implicit none
    integer :: np,it
    type(input),intent(in):: param
    double precision :: u
    double precision,intent(in) :: x(param%np),y(param%np),z(param%np)

    integer :: i,j
    double precision :: ddx,ddy,ddz,dd


    u=0.0e0

    do i=1,param%np-1
       do j=i+1,param%np

          ddx=x(i)-x(j)
          ddy=y(i)-y(j)
          ddz=z(i)-z(j)

          if (ddx > param%hbox) ddx=ddx-param%box
          if (ddy > param%hbox) ddy=ddy-param%box
          if (ddz > param%hbox) ddz=ddz-param%box

          if (ddx < -param%hbox) ddx=ddx+param%box
          if (ddy < -param%hbox) ddy=ddy+param%box
          if (ddz < -param%hbox) ddz=ddz+param%box

          dd=sqrt(ddx*ddx+ddy*ddy+ddz*ddz)

          if (dd <= param%rcut) then
             u = u + ( (param%sig/dd)**12 - (param%sig/dd)**6 )  
          endif

       enddo
    enddo

    u=u*4.0*param%eps


    return
  end subroutine energy




end module modmove_energy
```

Finally, the main program is as follows

```
program lennard

  use get_started
  use position
  use modmove_energy

  implicit none
  integer :: step,ar
  integer :: seed1,seed2
  type(input) :: param
  double precision, allocatable :: x(:),y(:),z(:)
  double precision :: potential

  seed1 = 2*int(secnds(0.0))
  seed2 = 1+seed1
  call srand(seed2)

  call init(param)
  call print_input(param)
  allocate (x(param%np),y(param%np),z(param%np))
  call init_position(param,x,y,z,0)


  do step=1,param%mceq
     call move(potential,param,x,y,z,ar)
    ! print*,potential
  enddo


  stop 
end program lennard
```

Comment: Have you tried skipping the `dd=0` values so as to not get a `NAN`?

Comment: Sorry if thats alot of code. I have gotten complaints on previous questions about not posting enough code. I am new to this forum, and am trying to learn how to go about asking these questions properly. Fanscescalus, yes that is the question.

Comment: Sure but even if they overlap, their positions won't be identically equal which is whats required for dd to be zero. Im outputting the positions of the particles when dd=0, and it says both particles are at (1.0*10^(-322),1.0*10^(-322),1.0*10^(-322)) every time. That can't be a coincidence.

Comment: [You need only have `param%sig/dd)**6` be infinity for the `NaN`.]  That's useful information you should add to the question.

Comment: Sure, but I just checked and param%sig is always one in the energy subroutine. So the issue is with dd I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking your guys time, and thank you for looking at this. The error was in subroutine move, I was assigning x(it) = xold, y(it)=yold,z(it)=zold before having defined xold,yold,zold. rookie mistake!

Comment: As that is indeed the problem, you should probably accept your answer.

Comment: It says I can't for two days.